# Pass object from main class to JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx

I have simple main class. 
There i try pass `user` to `WindowLogin` :

```
package client;


public class Client{

    public User user;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.run(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[ERR] Fatal error");
        }

    }

    public void run(String[] args)
    {

        user = new User();

        WindowLogin windowLogin = new WindowLogin();
        windowLogin.user = user;
        windowLogin.show();

    }

}
```

Window main class. There i try call `test()` function of `user` (in real, i need it pass to `WindowMainController`):

```
package client;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

import java.io.IOException;

public class WindowLogin extends Application{

    private Stage stage;
    public User user;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = new Stage();
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("views/WindowLogin.fxml"));

            WindowLoginController controller =
                    fxmlLoader.<WindowLoginController>getController();

            user.test();

            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void show(){
        launch();
    }
    public void hide() { stage.hide(); }

}
```

When i try to run it all:

`Exception in Application start method`

Of course (maybe :) ) it because of `user` in windowLogin is `null`.

What i doing wrong? How pass `user` to `windowLogin`? (i wont use Singletone)

---

Update:

I need use `user` in start() method, as i said before - i need pass `user` to `WindowMainController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OverView**

The problem you are facing here is on calling launch(), Javafx thread creates a new object of `WindowLogin`. So the object that you have created for `WindowLogin` and assigned user to it is no longer used in the start method !

```
 WindowLogin windowLogin = new WindowLogin();
 windowLogin.user = user;
```

You can overcome this by declaring the `User` in WindowLogin as static !

```
public static User user;
```

This will help to just keep on instance of the User

Comment: You solution works fine. But there one problem: i cant use `this.user` inside `start` method. It still shows `Exception in Application start method` when i do `user.test()`

Comment: A few options - its one and also one and also one option - Declare class as static :D.  Okay, i don't see another exit :( Thankyou for help ;)

Comment: You dont have to declare the class as static, just declare the reference of User object as static !